# proper syntax for grep: search a string, copy two rows above and transpose

Tags: command-line, scripts, grep

Am new (2 days old) to Linux and grep and am stuck here.
Scenario. I have data lasting more than 10yrs which I have been doing manually until I came across grep. The folders are of form `/yyyy/mm/dd` i.e. day1, day2 till end of month. I need to search for a specific string `iteration 8`. If found, then I need to copy the previous 3 rows from row where `iteration 8` is located. Then I need to transpose the into an output file. This is how am attempting to achieve my dilemma. Since am unable to transpose am trying to split the outputs then combine later. Please guide me on this case.

```
 for file in /filepath/snc* #adding full path
     do
      echo $file
       grep -r " Mean" $file | awk '{print $1 " " $2}'> mean.txt # to enable single columns for ease of manipulation later
       grep -r " RMS" $file | awk '{print $1 " " $2}' > rms.txt
       grep -r " o-c" $file | awk '{print $3 " "$4}' > o-c.txt
       grep -rl "iteration 8" $file > iteration.txt # to verify that the files are the correct ones
      done

paste iteration.txt o-c.txt mean.txt rms.txt > daily-summary.txt #the output file must be in this specific order
grep "iteration 8" daily-summary.txt | awk '{print $3 " " $4 " " $5 " " $6 " " $7 " " $8}' >> monthly-summary-path.txt

#grep -3 "iteration 8" daily-summary.txt  >> monthly-summary-file.txt # two lines before

rm mean.txt rms.txt std.txt
```

Sample input file:

```
            Mean    -78.6
            rms      1615
            o-c      1612.97456

iteration 8
```

Sample output file:

```
year month day o-c         mean  rms
2015   12   12  1612.97456 -78.6 1615
2015   12   11  1525.36589 -78.0 1642

=======================
```

Comment: Let's say you have two `iteration 8` strings in `day1` and one `iteration 8` string in `day2`. Do the target 6 lines of the first file and the target 3 lines of the second file go in different files? Do all 9 target lines go toghether in a single file? Else?

Comment: `-B` is the option of grep which allows you to print previous lines to a matched pattern. So `grep -B3 "iteration8" ...` will be a good start, though I'm sure you'll get some well crafted answers to help you achieve your entire goal. Also I think there's a typo in your question, as you switch from iteration8 to iteration18.

Comment: @kos Thanks. Ok. There can only one instance of iteration 8 or nothing at all per day.

Comment: Ok, so if there's one instance in `day1` and one instance in `day2`, do the three target lines in `day1` and the three target lines in `day2` go in different files or in the same output file?

Comment: @kos Ok let me try to clarify like this: top line is  mean (space) value1; second line is rms space value2 and last line is o-c (value3). The final output is in a spreadsheet that now has headers of yyyy mm dd o-c mean rms that's why I wanted to get it transposed so that I can just import the txt file into the template.

Comment: It's a bit hard to understand what you're after without looking at a sample input / sample output. Can you post a short sample input file and a sample of how the output file for that input file should look like?

Comment: @kos I am not sure whether its a browser error on my end but I hope that the images went through. I cant add any explanations so ill try to do it here. The first is the input file that runs more than 50 iterations. Sometimes the system exits before 50. In my thinking, since am interested in the o-c, mean & rms of iteration 8, I wanted to locate where iteration 8 is located then copy the above rows. The second image is the final expected output format. Thus I wanted a grep text output of the whole month (or year if possible) which I just import. blank lines means there was no iteration 8.

Comment: They went through, the problem is that you can't post pictures. I'm converting them to text and readding them to your question as such, since in this case text is better than a picture. Last question, are there always 3 empty lines before each `iteration` string (like in the example)?

Comment: I couldn't convert the image with an acceptable result, please repost at least the input as text, so that people can use it to test.

Comment: Yes. But I have noted an error on my part. IF mean occupies Row 1 then iteration will always occupy Row 5. Row 4 will always be blank. This is the same for all 50 iterations, in all the days of the month.

Comment: Maybe the simplest solution is that you post a whole input file (say `day1`) to [Ubuntu Pastebin](http://paste.ubuntu.com), so that we can directly see all possible cases. We should have enough informations to undertand what you want at this point.

Comment: As advised, i've pasted one example into the Ubuntu Pastebin. Not sure how it works but hope you can access it. This is for OneDay results and because its too long i only pasted about half. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @user3192045 you will need to provide the link URL for your pastebin - please [edit] it into your question instead of adding it in a comment

Comment: As steeldriver said please add the link to the pastebin URL. Anyway since I think I understood more or less what you want I added an answer below, see how it fits.

Answer (score 1):

This will create a report for a single month:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

@ARGV == 1 || die($!);

my $realpath = `realpath $ARGV[0]`;
chomp($realpath);

opendir(my $dir, $realpath) || die($!);

my @files;

while(readdir($dir)) {
    -f "$realpath/$_" && push(@files, "$realpath/$_");
}

print("year\tmonth\tday\to-c\tmean\trms\n");

my @realpath_s = split("/", $realpath);

foreach my $file (sort(@files)) {
    open(my $in, $file) || die($!);

    while(<$in>) {
        if(/^\s*Mean/) {
            my @row;
            for(my $i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
                my @F = split(/\s/);
                push(@row, $F[2]);
                $_ = <$in>;
            }
            $_ = <$in>;
            my @F = split(/\s/);
            if($F[1] == 8) {
                $file =~ s/.*day//;
                print("$realpath_s[@realpath_s-2]\t$realpath_s[@realpath_s-1]\t$file\t$row[2]\t$row[0]\t$row[1]\n");
                last;
            }
        }
    }
}

print("\n=======================\n");

exit 0;
```

Save it to, say, `~/script.pl`, and call it passing the path to the reports of a month:

```
perl ~/script.pl /path/to/2015/12
```

The output will be printed to the the terminal; you can use a redirection to redirect it to a file:

```
perl ~/script.pl /path/to/2015/12 > ~/report_2015_12.txt
```

It should be fairly easy to script multiple calls in a Bash script to create yearly / 10-year reports.

```
% tree
.
├── 2015
│   └── 12
│       ├── day1
│       ├── day2
│       └── day3
└── script.pl

2 directories, 4 files
% perl script.pl 2015/12
year    month   day o-c mean    rms
2015    12  1   1612.97456  -78.6   1615
2015    12  2   1612.97456  -79.6   1615
2015    12  3   1612.97456  -80.6   1615

=======================
```

In the example all files in `2015/12` contain a `iteration 8` line, hence a line is printed for each of them.

Comment: Thank you. Will have a look soon and revert. The output looks exactly as intended. @steeldriver, thanks for your input too.